# What's the difference between Homebrew's ruby and "Homebrew Ruby"?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

In my `brew --config` output I have the line

```
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
```

which confuses me because this is not the Ruby I've installed using

```
brew install ruby
```

nor the one that comes by default with my system (which are there only two on my PATH).

What's the difference between Homebrew-istalled ruby and "Homebrew Ruby"? Where are the gems for the latter?

Comment: This script seems to be responsible for fetching Homebrew's Ruby: [Library/Homebrew/utils/ruby.sh](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/utils/ruby.sh)

Comment: You shouldn't actually use `brew install ruby` to install/manage the Ruby versions that you use to develop Ruby applications. You want a Ruby version manager that doesn't mess with your system Ruby and installs gems in a path which doesn't require sudo. There a many choices such as RBenv, RVM, chruby etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the system version of Ruby is located at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby` but if you inspect closely the components of the path you will find out that `Current` is, in fact, a symlink:

This is how it looks like on my system (macOS Ventura 13.2):

```bash
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 Jan 14 02:57 2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    3 Jan 14 02:57 Current -> 2.6
```

It is the same version as the one reported by `brew --config`. Homebrew resolves the symlink and displays the real path of the Ruby executable.

The version of Ruby installed using `brew install ruby` is located somewhere else. Use `brew info ruby` to find out where it is installed. The location [depends on the hardware of your Mac computer](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location) (and it is also different on Linux).

Comment: So basically the "Homebrew Ruby" is (always) the system Ruby (and not the Ruby installed by Homebrew)?

Comment: I guess so. Homebrew needs Ruby to work. It cannot use the version of Ruby that it installs because it first needs to install it. The chicken and egg problem. I don't know why it does not use the version of Ruby that it installs **after** it installs it. Maybe the system version is first in the path (I never thought of this thing before.)

Comment: ... to continue the idea in the previous comment, Homebrew needs to use the system version of Ruby to also be able to run `brew uninstall ruby`. Also, one can install `rbenv` using Homebrew then they have multiple versions of Ruby installed on their system. Homebrew can rely only on the system Ruby. It should always be present on macOS. Even if it is an older version, it is usable for what Homebrew needs.

Comment: For additional information on system Ruby, I suggest reading https://dontusesystemruby.com.